# Facebook Deletion Request Callback - Trouble finding signed_request parameter in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-web-api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I've successfully integrated Facebook Login to my mobile app.
The mobile app has a server-side (ASP.NET) that must implement deletion callback (GDPR) acording to Facebook's guidance.

All works well (Facebook sucessfully calls my method), and I even have the implementation for the signed_request parsing.

HOWEVER - when I try to find the signed request parameter when the method executes, I can't find it!
the Content (`Request.Content`) of the call looks empty, the Uri doesn't have parameters, and I can't find the actual signed_request anywhere!

What am I missing?

I've tried decoding from Base64, ReadAsString, plain reading, nothing shows the parameter.
It looks like the whole request is empty.
Please advise, how can I find the signed_request in order to send it to my parsing method?

Thank you,

Yaron.

Comment: It’s a standard `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request, so if you don’t see any parameters, then you should start by figuring out whether the problem is on Facebook’s end, or yours. Send a request to your endpoint yourself, log all the received data, and see if that matches the expectation.

Comment: Thanks!

I'm pretty sure it's on my end..

I understand I need to decode a parameter from somewhere, just can't find what..

If it's around one line of code, I'd appreciate if you can write it here (I'm very good at marking accepted answers :-)

Comment: @YaronAdler were you able to implement the callback webmethod?

Comment: The same thing here, the POST request comes absolutely empty, literally nothing in it. I log all POST parameters and tested it myself, Facebook just doesn't send anything.